# Error when trying to set the iOS-application's background

Tags: ios, background-image, xcode7.3

Before I upgraded XCode to version 7.3.1 (7D1014), the following code snippet changed background of my application.

```
class InitialViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var startImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "FogCity")!)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Now I get following error: 
[image]

This image exists: 
[image]

The "print" function displays following: 
[image]

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, I tested it. I refer to this line of code:
`self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "FogCity")!)`

What you have to do is to check the name of the image **"FogCity"** to exactly match.

Answer (score 0):

Where is its 1x image? First put this image too, then try again...

Comment: It does not matter. If the application is designed for a specific device, you only need to use the image of the corresponding screen resolution.

Comment: Then check your image name is correctly matching or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use image name with extension like .png or .jpeg

```
 self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "FogCity.png")!)
```

Comment: Why do you advise variants which are guaranteed to lead to an error? There is should be no prefix, or filename extension, when referring to the image. Sorry for my English.